# PHP Array Manipulation

Tags: php, arrays

```
array
  324545432 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'Age' => int 1
          'Status' => string 'INSTALLED' 
          'Id' => string '830026495' 
          'name' => string 'TV' 
      1 => 
        array
          'Age' => int 2
          'Status' => string 'GOOD' 
          'Id' => string '553718299' 
          'name' => string 'Computer'
```

O/P Array should be of Structure:

```
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'Age' => int 0
          'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
          'Id' => string '830026495' 
          'name' => string 'TV' 
      1 => 
        array
          'Age' => int 0
          'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
          'Id' => string '553718299' 
          'name' => string 'Computer'
```

**Update:**

Input Array:

```
array
  324545433 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'Age' => int 0
          'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
          'Id' => string '830026495' 
          'name' => string 'TV' 
      1 => 
        array
          'Age' => int 0
          'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
          'Id' => string '553718299' 
          'name' => string 'Computer'         
array
  324545432 => 
        array
          0 => 
            array
              'Age' => int 0
              'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
              'Id' => string '830026495' 
              'name' => string 'TV' 
          1 => 
            array
              'Age' => int 0
              'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
              'Id' => string '553718299' 
              'name' => string 'Computer'
array
  324545431 => 
        array
          0 => 
            array
              'Age' => int 0
              'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
              'Id' => string '830026495' 
              'name' => string 'TV' 
          1 => 
            array
              'Age' => int 0
              'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
              'Id' => string '553718299' 
              'name' => string 'Computer'
array
  324545434 => 
        array
          0 => 
            array
              'Age' => int 0
              'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
              'Id' => string '830026495' 
              'name' => string 'TV' 
          1 => 
            array
              'Age' => int 0
              'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
              'Id' => string '553718299' 
              'name' => string 'Computer'
array
  324545430 => 
        array
          0 => 
            array
              'Age' => int 0
              'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
              'Id' => string '830026495' 
              'name' => string 'TV' 
          1 => 
            array
              'Age' => int 0
              'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
              'Id' => string '553718299' 
              'name' => string 'Computer'
```

.
.
.
.
.

Output Required:

```
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'Age' => int 0
          'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
          'Id' => string '830026495' 
          'name' => string 'TV' 
      1 => 
        array
          'Age' => int 0
          'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
          'Id' => string '553718299' 
          'name' => string 'Computer'
     2 => 
        array
          'Age' => int 0
          'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
          'Id' => string '830026495' 
          'name' => string 'TV' 
      3 => 
        array
          'Age' => int 0
          'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
          'Id' => string '553718299' 
          'name' => string 'Computer'
      4 => 
        array
          'Age' => int 0
          'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
          'Id' => string '830026495' 
          'name' => string 'TV' 
      5 => 
        array
          'Age' => int 0
          'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
          'Id' => string '553718299' 
          'name' => string 'Computer'
      6 => 
        array
          'Age' => int 0
          'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
          'Id' => string '830026495' 
          'name' => string 'TV' 
      7 => 
        array
          'Age' => int 0
          'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
          'Id' => string '553718299' 
          'name' => string 'Computer'     
      8 => 
        array
          'Age' => int 0
          'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
          'Id' => string '830026495' 
          'name' => string 'TV' 
      9 => 
        array
          'Age' => int 0
          'Status' => string 'INSTALLED/GOOD' 
          'Id' => string '553718299' 
          'name' => string 'Computer'
```

How can we achieve this ? Thing to note is that we can have many layers of '3242524621' like numbers which are associative array.

Thanks.

Comment: Does `$foo = array_shift($foo)` or `$foo = reset($foo)` work?

Comment: What if it has internal layers of many entities.

Comment: The question is not very clear, does not use consistent examples and includes too much irrelevant details. Why not just repeat konforce's code: $bar = array() ; foreach ($foo as $foo_part) $bar[]=$foo_part;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will set `$new_array` to the first value of `$original_array` no matter what the key is.

```
 function get_first($original_array)
 {
    foreach($original_array as $array)
    {
        return $array;
    }
}
$array = get_first($other_array);
```

You could also try [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) which will get the first value of `$original_array`, remove if from `$original_array` and return it, thus that the removed value is now set to `$new_array`

```
$new_array = array_shift($original_array);
```

You could probably make another function similar to the top one that would get rid of the destructive element.

```
function get_first($array)
{
    return array_shift($array);
}
```

Because arrays are passed by value and not reference, the array you pass into that function will remain intact.

Comment: Can you explain function get_first as I am having some difficulty understanding working of it.

Answer (score 3):

```
$k = array_keys($array);
return isset($k[0]) ? $array[$k[0]] : array();
```

Here you are :)